# How to resize the jQuery DatePicker control

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery DatePicker control for the first time. I've got it working on my form, but it's about twice as big as I would like, and about 1.5 times as big as the demo on the jQuery UI page. Is there some simple setting I'm missing to control the size?

**Edit:** I found a clue, but it opens up new problems. In the CSS file, it states the component will scale according to the parent element's font size. They recommend setting

```
body {font-size: 62.5%;}
```

to make 1em = 10px. Doing this gives me a nicely sized datepicker, but obviously it messes up the rest of my site (I currently have font-size: .9em).

I tried throwing a DIV around my text box and setting its font size, but it seems to ignore that. So there must be some way to shrink the datepicker by changing the font of its parent, but how do I do that without messing up the rest of my site?

Comment: paste your code up, cause i know no reason why it would be bigger? and are your referring to the image button or the actual calendar that shows the days?

Comment: I've noticed that the datepicker HTML will be inserted outside of any containing div. That's why setting the font size of your div didn't do it (aside from the fact that the style declaration needed to be more specific, like in Jimmy Stenke's answer).

Answer (score 392, accepted):

You don't have to change it in the jquery-ui css file (it can be confusing if you change the default files), it is enough if you add

```
div.ui-datepicker{
 font-size:10px;
}
```

in a stylesheet loaded after the ui-files

div.ui-datepicker is needed in case ui-widget is mentioned after ui-datepicker in the declaration

Comment: The "in a stylesheet loaded after the ui-files" step is very important. If you load your stylesheet before the jquery ui stylesheet, any attributes you set will be overwritten.

Comment: To stop the overwritten issue as per comment 1 - you can do this:

font-size:10px !important;

Comment: !important is hack-ish, i'd definitely advise against using that.

Comment: This is why they are called CASCADING Style Sheets (CSS)

Comment: lol didn't even notice that the problem could be the font-size! thank you

Comment: Millions Dollar Answer Man :)

Comment: I added your suggestion onto the last line of the `jquery-ui.css` file instead of creating a separate stylesheet and then having to remember to add it to every webpage.

Answer (score 30):

I can't add a comment, so this is in reference to the accepted answer by Keijro.  I actually added the following to my stylesheet instead:

```
    div.ui-datepicker {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

and it worked as well.  This might be preferable to the absolute value of 10px.

Answer (score 23):

Not sure whether some body has suggested following way, if yes, just ignore my comments. I tested this today and it works for me. By just resizing the font before the control gets displayed:

```
$('#event_date').datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    beforeShow: function(){    
           $(".ui-datepicker").css('font-size', 12) 
    }
});
```

Using the callback function beforeShow

Comment: I like this solution better

Answer (score 9):

I change the following line in ui.theme.css:

```
.ui-widget { font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1.1em; }
```

to:

```
.ui-widget { font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
```

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
div.ui-datepicker, .ui-datepicker td{
 font-size:10px;
}
```

in a stylesheet loaded after the ui-files.
This will also resize the date items.

Answer (score 5):

For me, this was the easiest solution:
I added the `font-size:62.5%;` to the first `.ui-datepicker` tag in the jquery custom css file:

before:

```
.ui-datepicker { width: 17em; padding: .2em .2em 0; display: none;}
```

after:

```
.ui-datepicker { width: 17em; padding: .2em .2em 0; display: none; font-size:62.5%; }
```

Answer (score 4):

I was trying these examples without success. Apparently other stylesheets on the page were setting default font sizes for different tags. If you adjust the ui-datepicker you are changing a div.  If you change a div you need to make sure the contents of that div inherit that size.  This is what finally worked for me:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker-calendar tr, .ui-datepicker-calendar td, .ui-datepicker-calendar td a, .ui-datepicker-calendar th{font-size:inherit;}
div.ui-datepicker{font-size:16px;width:inherit;height:inherit;}
.ui-datepicker-title span{font-size:16px;}
</style>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I was using an input to collect and show the calendar, and to be able to resize the calendar I have been using this code:

```
div.ui-datepicker, .ui-datepicker input{font-size:62.5%;}
```

It works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

`$('.ui-datepicker').css('font-size', $('.ui-datepicker').width() / 20 + 'px');`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me and seems simple...

```
$(function() {
  $('#inlineDatepicker').datepicker({onSelect: showDate, defaultDate: '01/01/2010'});
});

<div style="font-size:75%";>
<div id="inlineDatepicker"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with out changing the css file you can also change the calendar size  by putting the the following code in to ur <head>.....</head> tag:


<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Icon trigger</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<style type="text/css">
.ui-widget { font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 0.6em; }
</style>

<script>



$(function() {

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
//font-size:10px;
 //numberOfMonths: 3,

showButtonPanel: true,
showOn: 'button',
buttonImage: "images/calendar1.gif",
buttonImageOnly: true
});
});
</script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the approach of using the callback function beforeShow but found I had to also set the line height.  My version looked like:

```
beforeShow: function(){$j('.ui-datepicker').css({'font-size': 11, 'line-height': 1.2})}
```

Answer (score 1):

the best place to change the size of the calendar is in the file jquery-ui.css

```
/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: .7em; /* <--default is 1.1em */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will work on Calender buttons.
size of numbers will increase by using "line-height".

```
/* Change Size */
<style>
    .ui-datepicker{
        font-size:16px;
        line-height: 1.3;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css as follows

```
.ui-widget
{
    font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.6em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
$('.your-container').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, datepickerInstance) {
        datepickerInstance.dpDiv.css('font-size', '11px');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('div.ui-datepicker').css({ fontSize: '12px' });` work if we call it after 
`$("#DueDate").datepicker();`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdncaewx/)

Answer (score 1):

The Jacob Tsui solution works perfect for me:

```
$('#event_date').datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    beforeShow: function(){ 
        $(".ui-datepicker").css('font-size', 12)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We can alter in the default '**jquery-ui.css**' file as below given code:

```
div.ui-datepicker {
font-size: 80%; 
}
```

However, changing the default '**jquery-ui.css**' file is not recommended as it might have been used somewhere else in the project. Changing values in the default file can alter datepicker font in other webpages where it has been used.

I used the below code to alter "font-size". I placed it just after datepicker() is called as shown below.

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
            $("div.ui-datepicker").css("font-size", "80%")
        });
</script>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it - I had to go into the CSS file and change the font-size for the datepicker control directly. Obvious once you know about it, but confusing at first.

Answer (score 0):

open ui.all.css

at the end put

```
@import "ui.base.css";
@import "ui.theme.css";

div.ui-datepicker {
font-size: 62.5%; 
}
```

and go !

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work in Safari 5.1 with Rails 3.1, I had to add:

```
.ui-datepicker, .ui-datepicker a{
 font-size:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had datepicker appearing in a modal and because of the "date-display-container" on the left hand side, the calendar was partially out of view, so I added:

```css
.datepicker-date-display {
  display: none;
}

.datepicker-calendar-container {
  max-height: 21em;
}
.datepicker-day-button {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.datepicker-table > thead > tr > th {
  padding: 0;
}
```