# How to resize jQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui, resize, datepicker

I have jQuery Datepicker inside my form.

My problem is after I have clicked inside textfield, datepicker shows too big.

How can I resize datepicker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659588/how-to-resize-the-jquery-datepicker-control)

I quote -

> add **in a stylesheet loaded after the ui-files**

```
div.ui-datepicker{
 font-size:10px;
}
```

Comment: that's great..fiuhh i almost make change at datepicker's css...thanks