# IDE Like interface with jQuery (Resizing divs)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am planning to develop a site which will have interface very similar to IDE

[image]

I was wondering if there is a jQuery plugin which allows the resizing of divs (horizontal / vertical based on settings) or any ideas on what would be the best approach.

Comment: For something like this, extjs [ http://www.sencha.com/products/js/ ] is a more natural fit. You can still use jquery of course, but I would recommend you take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use jQuery layout for a web-based publishing platform for kids books and it's really good. Simple to use, good docs.

http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#resizable").resizable();
    });
</script>


<div id="resizable" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: silver;"></div>
```

**Reference:**

- [UI/API/1.8/Resizable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Resizable)
- [Custom Resizable Handles in JQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659588/how-to-resize-the-jquery-datepicker-control)
- [jQuery Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/)

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery UI Re-sizable

http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/