# How to change the size of jquery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resize the jQuery DatePicker control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659588/how-to-resize-the-jquery-datepicker-control)

Please tell me how to change the size of the jquery ui datepicker. My default datepicker `width` and `height` are close to `308px` and `285px`. This is too large for my page. Please tell me how to re size it?. Why it become that much large? I only did copying and pasting the code and replace css and js files in to relevant places.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/ui/jquery.ui.all.css">   

<script src="./js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>    
<script src="./js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="./js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="./js/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: [go to this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659588/how-to-resize-the-jquery-datepicker-control) you will find proper answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$('div.ui-datepicker').css({
   font-size:10px;
});
```

increasing the font size will increase the overall size of the datapicker.

Comment: $('div.ui-datepicker').css({ fontSize: '12px' });

should do the trick.

Comment: Like this is better:

$("div.ui-datepicker").css(
      {
       "font-size": "12px"
      }
     );

;)

Comment: This trick not work for a drop data picker...because the Div not create yet to access it via CSS or also via jquery by set css...... for drop-down Data Picker it just work if we use `$('div.ui-datepicker').css({ fontSize: '12px' });` after call `$("#date-start").datepicker();`.

Comment: If I don't want to change font size, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
.ui-datepicker {
    height: 500px ;
    padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0;
    width: 150px;
}
```

in your `jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css`. note that `1.8.6` is the version I am using.

Comment: This method not good way....we shouldn't edit core of some library