# Resizing jquery-ui datepicker misplaces it

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery-ui to add a date-picker to a form.

The form looks like this

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td class="c1"><input class="datepicker" type="text" name='date'/></td>
 <td class="c2"><input type="text" name='heading'/></td>
 <td class="c3"><input type="text" name='comments'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I added the date-picker but it was too huge [image]

So I added this line to resize it

```
<style media=\"screen\" type=\"text/css\">
 .ui-datepicker{
  font-size:12px;
 }
</style>
```

It worked but there was a problem. The datepicker now hides the form.

[image]

How can I position it as before with the date-picker's top aligned to the fields bottom.

Comment: Just a long shot - are there any errors in the css code or html markup? You can check them here http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input and http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input .

Answer (score 1):

Ref this link:

```
div.ui-datepicker{
  font-size:12px;
}
```

http://quickwiki.com/How_to_resize_jQuery_datepicker_calendar_size

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [How to resize the jQuery DatePicker control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659588/how-to-resize-the-jquery-datepicker-control)

You need to add that style definition at the end of the jq-ui css file.

So put this at the end:

```
div.ui-datepicker{
 font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: Plus it does not matter whether I specify the style in actual html file or the css file. The one in the HTML will be the one that will be applied last AFIK.

Comment: Please make sure that if you use saratis's solution, that you remove inline style from the html page. 'div' part before 'ui.datepicker{font-size:12px};} should not be left out, too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an !important attribute?

```
.ui-datepicker {font-size: 12px !important;}
```

And have you tried this? Probably not what you want but I'm curious for the result ^^

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ autoSize: true });
```

Comment: ah pitty, thought it had a good chance but didnt feel like testing it.
just pushing off some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code :

```
<style type="text/css">
 table.post-meta tr, td {
 font-size:7px; 
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
        $( "#datepicker " ).datepicker( );
        $("#datepicker   .ui-datepicker").css({"font-size":"7px"}); 
         $("#datepicker   .ui-datepicker a").css({"font-size":"7px"}); 
    });
</script>
```