# How to customize the size of struts-jquery-tags calendar

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

In my struts2 application i am using `struts-jquery-tags`. Using this tag library am  making calendar attribute but it is appearing  very big .I want to make it small. But am not getting any way to do it.

```
<sj:datepicker  name="date" label="Aggrement DATE" changeMonth="true" changeYear="true"/>
```

Comment: I am just using this code for date calendar but the calender size is little bulky as compare   to my form size. I just want to customize  the calendar size ..

Comment: There's a `size` attribute you could play.

Comment: @ Roman Give me an example or link to some tutorials . I checked your answers on other post about struts-jquery they are not just enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by overriding the default style sheet of jQuery UI by adding your own style, exactly as for the standard jQuery DatePicker:

Put this in head *after* the jQuery CSS import.

```
<style>
   div.ui-datepicker {
      font-size: 62.5%;
   }
</style>
```

You can write an entire new jQuery theme from scratch, but usually you will only need to override some properties, like in this case.

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659588/how-to-resize-the-jquery-datepicker-control)

Answer (score 0):

we can customise struts calender or datetimepicker with Firebug ( Awesome plugin for firefox ), Every developer should know this approach.

http://forums.java4s.com/Thread-How-to-change-the-color-of-datetimepicker-in-struts2

Check this link.

Regards