# Dynamically auto-size a jQuery Datepicker to make it fit a div

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I'm using a jQuery datepicker (UI 1.10) in the in-line mode. I do not find a way to dynamically re-size it to a 100% of the div in which it lives (width and height). I have found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659588/how-to-resize-the-jquery-datepicker-control) forum ways to resize the datepicker changing the font-size but I need something that would let me do something like

```
#Datepicker
{width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

So far, I've been able to partially change the size by using

```
div.ui-datepicker{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

table.ui-datepicker-calendar{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.ui-state-default{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

#DayEvents
{
 width:50%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 float:right;
 position:relative;
}
```

but it looks ugly because some child divs and tables would be cropped because of padding & margins.

What would be the easiest and most maintainable way to do this? Are there other jQuery tools that would show a calendar and let me pick a date that I should look into? I'd assume datepicker is exactly what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the skinny.

Edit ALL of the ".ui-*" selectors in the CSS file, removing ALL references to pixels, points, etc, etc. ALL sizes much be expressed in "em" units.

Then edit the topmost selector in the CSS file as follows:

```
.ui-datepicker
{
    font-size: 12px; /* Entire calendar scales by this value. same as 9pt*/
```

This must the ONLY pixel value in the CSS file.

As a rule of thumb, replace 3px with 0.3em, 10px with 1.0em etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('input').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        inst.dpDiv.outerWidth($('input').outerWidth());
      }, 0);
    },
  });

  $('.ui-datepicker').on('click',function(){
    $(this).outerWidth($('input').outerWidth());
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).